# Node setInterval in prototype

Tags: setinterval

can anybody explain me why setInterval did not work in an prototype?
Im using Node v4.8.2

```
function timers(){
         console.log("new timer");
}


timers.prototype.start = function(){
    console.log("starting timer with interval: 1000");
    setInterval(function(){console.log("aa");}, 1000);
}

timer = new timers();

timer.start();

while (true) {

}
```

the output is only:

```
new timer
starting timer with interval: 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript isn't multi-threaded. Your while(true) {} is blocking execution of the setInterval. Take that out and see what happens.